# Web AppBuilder's "Near Me" widget doesn't work with my point layer?

Tags: arcgis-online, widget, arcgis-web-appbuilder, configuration

[image]

So I added a zipped shapefile of point data from a file.  This was put on a Web Map and this Web Map is connected to a Web AppBuilder.

I would like to use this "Near Me" widget to locate points closest to an address that is entered. However, the widget says my layers aren't configured properly.   How can I configure my layer or make this work?  Am I missing something in the attribute field?

Comment: So, I've had the same issue when configuring my web app with the Near Me widget. I wanted to confirm, the widget DOES NOT work with a zipped shapefile, and the layer must be published as a hosted feature layer. Is this correct? Thanks!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/127190)

Answer (score 1):

When you choose the near me widget you have the option in WAB to select your layer you want to use. Did you pick the layer you want to use or just enable the widget?

Comment: I tried to pick the layer within the widget settings but it doesn't appear as an option.

Comment: Did you publish the zip shapefile as a hosted feature layer in Online or is it in the map as a feature collection? I am thinking it is currently in the map as a feature collection and will need to be a feature layer to  work with the near me widget.

Answer (score 0):

upload the point layer as a hosted feature service to ArcGIS Online.
Procedure is outlined [HERE](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/share-maps/publish-features.htm)